# checkbox is unchecked, but is not refreshed in page

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 2 pages, of which one is a lightbox. When I click cancel in my lightbox, I trigger a function in my parent page to uncheck a checkbox. The state of my checkbox gets unchecked, but the check mark isn't removed.  Only if I refresh the page, the check mark is removed. How do I remove the check mark? I am using jQuery.

```
 <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" value="krisflyer" id="chkbox"/>
 <a href="lightbox.html?KeepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=600&width=950&modal=true" class="thickbox" id="lightbox"></a>
 <input type="hidden" id="cancelfunc" />   //Edited

 $("#cancelfunc").click(function(){
       $("#chkbox").attr("checked", false);
       tb_remove();
 })
```

In my lightbox:

```
 <a id="cancel_lightbox" href="#">Cancel</a>  //Edited

 $('#cancel_lightbox').click(function(){
window.parent.$("#cancelfunc").click();
return false;
 })
```

**Update**

Sorry, I forgot to mention one thing. I had been using images for the checkbox. If I remove the class that adds the images, the code works fine. The checkbox is checked and unchecked correctly. Only with the images, they do not change appropriately.

Comment: How do you know that "the state of [the] checkbox gets unchecked" if "the check mark isn't removed"?

Comment: The lightbox will load only when the checkbox is unchecked, and I check the checkbox. If the box is checked, and I click it, a dialog box should open. But in this case, the checkbox is checked, but wen I click, instead of the dialog box, the lightbox opens. So with that I found that the state of the checkbox is unchecked. And also, When I refresh the page, the checkbox is unchecked.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the syntax you've got for unchecking the checkbox, see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Town/zZcL3/). Which browser is this? Is your child page definitely finding the element in the parent?

Comment: That checkbox starts unchecked, so refreshing the page will return it to an unchecked state.

Comment: Could you post some more code? What type are the `cancelfunc` and `cancel_lightbox` elements?

Comment: @ Town : Its Moxilla Firefox. But if I refresh the page without unchecking the checkbox, the checkbox remains checked. `cancelfunc` is a input element and `cancel_ligthbox` is a link. I've edited my code, chk that

Comment: Can't you change the click function of the checkbox from click to change? And get the .val() and equals that to true instead of binding it to a click.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will solve it but this is how I would uncheck the box, with [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$("#cancelfunc").click(function(){
       $("#chkbox").removeAttr("checked");
       tb_remove();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#cancelfunc").click(function(){
       $("#chkbox").checked = false;
       tb_remove();
 })
```

Comment: And how about this: $('input[id=chkbox]').attr('checked', false);

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$("#chkbox").attr("checked", "");
```